# Loading custom property in Excel Online

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js, office-addins

I want to try execute this function for Office API for JavaScript:

```
public loadCustomProperties() {
    Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
        let custom = ctx.workbook.properties.custom;    
        custom.load();
        return ctx.sync();
    })
}
```

But I got an error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): GeneralException: An internal error occurred...` (nothing specific)

When I'm trying to load `properties` instead of `properties.custom` everything works fine.

Please help :)

**EDIT:**
This is the error I get:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): GeneralException: An internal
>   error occurred while processing the request.
>       RichApi.Error: An internal error occurred while processing the request.
>           at new r (excel-web-16.00.js:21)
>           at t.c.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (excel-web-16.00.js:21)
>           at excel-web-16.00.js:21
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:388)
>           at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3760)
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:387)
>           at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
>           at zone.js:872
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3751)
>           at new r (excel-web-16.00.js:21)
>           at t.c.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (excel-web-16.00.js:21)
>           at excel-web-16.00.js:21
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:388)
>           at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3760)
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:387)
>           at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
>           at zone.js:872
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3751)
>           at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>           at zone.js:724
>           at rejected (main.js:103)
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:388)
>           at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3760)
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:387)
>           at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
>           at zone.js:872
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3751)

**EDIT 2:**

I found this is a known bug: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/179

Comment: Why are you using an async function without await in the body? Whats the point? Your problem might go away if you remove the async keyword

Comment: It doesn't change anything. The error is shown when executing `ctx.sync()` so at this moment it doesn't matter what I do with `custom` because after `ctx.sync()` it breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've came up with this workaround method to load items. It turns out that if you ensure that count is greater than 0, you can safely load customProperties.

```
async function loadCustomPropertiess() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        var customProperty = context.workbook.properties.custom;
        var customPropertyCount = customProperty.getCount();
        await context.sync();

        if (customPropertyCount.value > 0) {
            customProperty.load();
            await context.sync();
            customProperty.items.forEach(prop => console.log(prop));
        } else {
            console.log("No custom properties");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

modified code with 3 changes.

1. missing async on first line
2. missing 'function'
3. finally as shanks mentions, you are missing the await on the context.sync()

and I added a console.log just to verify that properties were loaded and they are.

```js
async function loadCustomProperties() {
   await Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
        let custom = ctx.workbook.properties.custom;
        custom.load();
        await ctx.sync();
        console.log(custom);
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried your function but the error is the same, as I said, it works for `properties` but it doesn't for `custom`